# Gerar Token API acesso

Tags: c#, api, .net-core

Bom dia,

Vou enviar um link pelo meu sistema para o cliente ter acesso, até ai já está tudo ok, porém eu queria enviar um token para validar, junto com o link, e na hora do cliente acessar a página, ele validar o token se tiver tudo certo, ele acessar, senão informa que não tem acesso.

Igual faço quando vou resetar a senha que utilizo do prório `identity

```
 var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
        var encodedToken = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token);
```

E ai depois eu utilizo o decode

```
   var decodedToken = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(model.Token);
```

Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer ?  Para não ter brechas de segurança no sistema. Essa é a minha maior preocupação.

Answer (score -1):

Utilize alguma criptografia simétrica que apenas a sua aplicação consiga descriptografar.

Gere um link de acesso passando as informações que quiser por parametro.

```
  //Algo que voce consiga identificar o usuario
  int idUsuario;

  //Data que o link é valido
  DateTime LinkExpirado;

  //url do seu site
  string UrlAplicacao;

 //Link que você irá mandar para o cliente acessar
 string UrlEnviarCliente = $"{UrlAplicacao}/usuarios/{MetodoCriptografia(idUsuario)}/{MetodoCriptografia(LinkExpirado)}";
```

Agora basta você criar um controller para o acesso.

```
 [Route("usuarios/{identificador}/{LinkExpirado}")]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public async Task<IActionResult> ValidaAcessoUsuario(string identificador, string LinkExpirado) 
 {
    string idUsuario = MetodoDescriptografa(identificador);
    string dataExpirado = MetodoDescriptografa(LinkExpirado);
 }
```

Agora você faz as validações necessárias, verificando se é um usuario valido, se a data ainda não foi expirada ...

Em relação a segurança, você pode passar mais informações por parametro e garantir uma chave forte para sua criptografia, não vejo muito o que mais possa ser feito.